# Using Aysnc/await with Props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use async and await with props.

So basically I have a onRefresh function which refreshes when user scrolls down.

Here, i want to change the state to false once my reducer have successfully updated the data

```
onRefresh = () => {
        this.setState({isFetching: true}, () => {
            refreshData = async () => {
            await this.props.indianCurrency()
            await this.props.exchangeToDisplay(this.coinURL, true)
            await  this.setState({isFetching: false})
            }
        })

    }
```

In await `this.props.indianCurrency()`  action I have added a `console.log` statement to see if it is being executed it or not.

This is my action for indianCurrency

```
export const indianCurrency = () => {
  console.log("inside Indian currency")
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: CURRENCY_FETCHING})
    axios.get(CurrencyRateLinkINR).then((response) => {
      return (
        dispatch({
          type: CURRENCY_INR,
          payload: response.data
        })
      )
    }).catch((error) => {
      return (
        dispatch({
          type: CURRENCY_ERROR,
          payload: error.data
        })
      )
    })
  }
}
```

and for exchangeToDisplay my action looks like this

```
export const exchangeToDisplay = (exchangURL, random) => {
    console.log(random)
    console.log("on Refresh check as well")
    return function (dispatch) {
            if (random == undefined) {
               dispatch({type: EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCHING })
             }
            let koinexApi = axios.get(koinex)
            let coinDeltaApi = axios.get(coinDelta)
            let multipleExchangeDataApi = axios.get(multipleExchangeData + exchangURL + "-usd") 
            Promise.all([koinexApi, coinDeltaApi , multipleExchangeDataApi]).then(function(values) {
                return(
                    dispatch({
                        type: EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        payload: values
                    })
                 )   
            }).catch((error) => {
                return (
                    dispatch({
                        type: EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCH_ERROR,
                        payload: error
                    })
                )
             })
    }
}
```

And for my surprise nothing isn't logging out there. So I have reason to believe that I am not using async/await correctly here? So can someone guide me on how to use async and await correctly?

**Note:** I am purposely not pasting `reducer code` and  because I believe that problem happens to be in my async/await since it isn't even running `export const indianCurrency = () => {` if in case it is required then do let me know and I will paste it.

Comment: you need to await axios.get, because that code is a promise as well

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Can you please explain it in stretch in answer section?

Comment: @KuchBhi He's stating that `axios` requests are asynchronous, therefore you need to `await` it as well. You're mixing `.then` and `async/await`. Stick to one pattern. Either wrap your `async/await` into simple `try/catch` blocks, or chain your promises with `.then(...).then(...).then(...)`. Read this for more information: https://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you're not returning the promise.

So if you change

```
...
axios.get(...)
```

to

```
...
return axios.get(...)
```

then your top level awaits (like `await this.props.indianCurrency()`) will actually *wait* for the promise.

Another option is to make your fetch code async (you still need to return a value though):

```
export const indianCurrency = async () => {
  ...
  const results = await axios.get(...)
  return results
}
```

Needless to say, same goes for `Promise.all(...)` - either `return Promise.all(...)` or make it async/await.

Also, as @NoobieSatan points out in comments, your `refreshData` code seems suspicious. Why are you defining a function inside a the state callback? Maybe you meant to define it outside and **call** it inside?

```
refreshData = async () => {
    await this.props.indianCurrency()
    await this.props.exchangeToDisplay(this.coinURL, true)
    this.setState({isFetching: false}) // you don't need await here
}

onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({isFetching: true}, refreshData)
}
```

But then again, this is not how or why you would use the `setState` callback. If your intent is to show a loading sign and then just fire some background fetch, then you should just call `refreshData` after `setState`

```
onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({isFetching: true})
    refreshData()
}
```

Once `refreshData`, completes (you still need to return the promise for async/await to work), it'll update the state and React will re-render the component correctly. And you don't need to await setState.

Comment: Also he isn't calling function `refreshData` in the first place

Comment: @Mrchief since there are two code snippets, this way I am not returning promise in my second code as well? secondly when I do  `axios.get(CurrencyRateLinkINR).then((response) => {
      return (` Am I not returning the promise?

Comment: @KuchBhi Nope. Unless you `return axios.get`, the inner `return` is not returned to the caller.

Comment: @NoobieSatan yeah, that's another problem. Good catch!